# node http server stop doesn't shut down connections

Tags: node.js, http, testing

I've been looking for a while in a lot of threads about how to shut down an `http` server in `nodejs`.
I couldn't find a simple way to test my web app.

I'm trying to test my server, writing integration test.
I want to simulate errors as well, hence I start the server with different configurations.

For example:

```
const app = express()
...
app.use('/route', createRouter(argA, argB)
const server = http.createServer(app)
```

I want to test that if `argA` throws an error, my server return `500`,
as well as `argB`.

So I want to start the server with a mock of `argA` that throws,
then close the server and start it again with a mock of `argB` that throws.

But, the `http` server of `nodejs` doesn't close connected sockets,
so I cant do something like this:

```
beforeEach((done) => server.start(done))
afterEach((done) => server.stop(done))
```

Where `start` execute `listen` and `stop` execute `close`.
The server fails to start since the `port` is already in use.

How can I manage to start and stop the server with different configurations?

Comment: I figured out the error, it is `ECONNRESET`, from the http client lib (using `axios`). I guess it is because I closed the server, and then started it again. But why doesn't it work? I should be able to listen again, `The server.listen() method can be called again if and only if there was an error during the first server.listen() call or server.close() has been called` from the docs.

Comment: destroying the sockets shouldn't resolve this?

Comment: hmm.. ok. Do you know if I can disable the keep alive from the client instead of messing the server?

Comment: ok, done. thank you :)